# Invalid Hook Call useSelector() with react-router

Tags: javascript, react-redux, react-router-dom

I have my state in Redux working for a shopping cart. Let's say I have two pages and want to pass the state from the shopping page to the cart/checkout page.

I am calling useSelector from this page but I get an error about an invalid Hook Call.

```
const CartPage = () => {
    const selectedProducts = useSelector(
        (state) => (state && state.products) || []
    );
    
    return (
        <PageContainer>
            This is the Cart Page
        </PageContainer>);
};

export default CartPage;
```

And this component is rendered by react-dom-router like this

```
<AppContainer>
  <Navigation />
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" render={WelcomePage} />
      <Route path="/cart" render={CartPage} />
      <Route path="/shopping" render={ShoppingPage} />
    </Switch>
</AppContainer>
```

I am storing the state from a component inside the page component ShoppingPage.

The useSelector hook is working only inside components outside the react-router-dom. Is there a way to get the state in one of these components?

Comment: You can use a common context provider to  share some variable between your components.
https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper

Comment: Could you paste the whole invalid hook call? Because I have the same setup as you and didn't get any errors.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Somehow it worked using a callback inside the render attribute of Route

Here the fixed code

```
<AppContainer>
  <Navigation />
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" render={() => <WelcomePage /> } />
      <Route path="/cart" render={() => <CartPage /> } />
      <Route path="/shopping" render={() => <ShoppingPage /> } />
    </Switch>
</AppContainer>
```